# Send larger messages than 126 bytes websockets

Tags: c#, google-chrome, websocket

Now I'm working on Websockets, I'm new in that, I finally can send a message of 126 bytes, but I need send longer messages but when I try the connection is closed automatically, my code is:

```
    public void sendMessage(Stream stream, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            List<byte> lb = new List<byte>();
            string aux = message;
            bool flagStart = false;
            int size;
            while (message.Length > _maxLengthMessage)
            {
                lb = new List<byte>(); 
                // I cut the mesasge in smaller pieces to send
                message = aux.Substring(0, _maxLengthMessage); 
                aux = aux.Substring(_maxLengthMessage);
                if (!flagStart)
                {
                    // In doc of Websockets i sign this piece: not the end, text
                    lb.Add(0x01);
                    flagStart = !flagStart;
                }
                else
                {
                    // In doc of Websockets i sign this piece: not the end, continuation
                    lb.Add(0x00);
                }
                size = message.Length;

                lb.Add((byte)size);
                lb.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                stream.Write(lb.ToArray(), 0, size + 2);             
            }
            lb = new List<byte>();
            if (!flagStart)
            {
                // If is this the only message we mark with: end of message, text
                lb.Add(0x81);
                flagStart = !flagStart;
            }
            else
            {
                //else Is the end of the message but is the continuation frame
                lb.Add(0x80);
            } 
            size = aux.Length;

            lb.Add((byte)size);
            lb.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aux));
            //lb.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i.ToString()));
            stream.Write(lb.ToArray(), 0, size+2);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Some answers say "Go to the The WebSocket protocol", but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi ralp, Can you put your corrected code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to write the message length needs to be extended.  The extended payload in the data framing diagram of [the protocol spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5) shows what's missing.

For messages up to 125 bytes, your code is correct.

For messages > 125 but <= 65536 bytes, you need to write 3 bytes - the first byte is 126; the following 2 bytes give the message length.

For messages > 65536 bytes, you need to write 9 bytes - the first byte is 127; the following 8 bytes give the message length.

Answer (score 1):

Ye, you have to create correct frame, here is the method:

```
static private byte[] CreateFrame(string message, MessageType messageType = MessageType.Text, bool messageContinues = false)
    {
        byte b1 = 0;
        byte b2 = 0;

        switch (messageType)
        {
            case MessageType.Continuos:
                b1 = 0;
                break;
            case MessageType.Text:
                b1 = 1;
                break;
            case MessageType.Binary:
                b1 = 2;
                break;
            case MessageType.Close:
                b1 = 8;
                break;
            case MessageType.Ping:
                b1 = 9;
                break;
            case MessageType.Pong:
                b1 = 10;
                break;
        }

        b1 = (byte)(b1 + 128); // set FIN bit to 1

        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        if (messageBytes.Length < 126)
        {
            b2 = (byte)messageBytes.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            if (messageBytes.Length < Math.Pow(2,16)-1)
            {                   
                b2 = 126;

            }
            else
            {
                b2 = 127;
            }

        }

        byte[] frame = null;

        if(b2 < 126)
        {
            frame = new byte[messageBytes.Length + 2];
            frame[0] = b1;
            frame[1] = b2;
            Array.Copy(messageBytes, 0, frame, 2, messageBytes.Length);
        }
        if(b2 == 126)
        {
            frame = new byte[messageBytes.Length + 4];
            frame[0] = b1;
            frame[1] = b2;
            byte[] lenght = BitConverter.GetBytes(messageBytes.Length);
            frame[2] = lenght[1];
            frame[3] = lenght[0];
            Array.Copy(messageBytes, 0, frame, 4, messageBytes.Length);
        }

        if(b2 == 127)
        {
            frame = new byte[messageBytes.Length + 10];
            frame[0] = b1;
            frame[1] = b2;
            byte[] lenght = BitConverter.GetBytes((long)messageBytes.Length);

            for(int i = 7, j = 2; i >= 0; i--, j++)
            {
                frame[j] = lenght[i];
            }
        }

        return frame;
    }
```