# C# Web Socket: Send string larger than 125 bytes

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, tcp, websocket

As title suggests, I'm trying to send strings over 125 bytes, and as I've read around, the bytes has to be divided to two frames containing the length. I've tried around, messed up my own code, trying to do as said. And since I'm not having any luck, I'm turning to StackOverflow.

What I need to do is send a string containing a dynamically amount of letters (estimated to be 2000), when I do this, I receive errors in the client and server. `WebSocket Protocol Error`
and the client: `Invalid frame header`.

I'd appreciate any help regarding this, thank you.

```
public static void SendHeader(TcpClient client, int client_port, string header)
{
    ConsoleHandler.debug("Sent header to " + users.Users.Clients[client_port].ClientIP + ":" + client_port.ToString() + ": " + header);

    Byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("99" + header);
    response[0] = 0x81;
    response[1] = (byte)(response.Length - 2);
    client.GetStream().Write(response, 0, response.Length);
}
```

Comment: Why so much data in the Header?  Can you send the large chunk of data after you have sent the header?

Comment: I'd rather keep it in one header. The data I'm sending is 5 columns from a database.

Comment: This seems wrong by design, doesn't it? If those strings are long, I would naturally put them in the messages' body. Why is it so crucial putting your strings in the header?

Comment: Oh well, my bad. This is the message body. Even if I'd put it in a seperate packet, it's too long to be transmitted. See this: `SocketManager.SendHeader(client, client_port, "LandingViewPromos: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database.cache.WebPromosTable.Caches[i]));`

Comment: @LuicyWillowfield: the payload of a single websocket frame can have a size of up to 2^71 bytes. See [Base Framing Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2) in the standard of how to specify a length of more than 127 bytes.

Comment: Ìf you'd pay attention to what I said, I already tried around with that, however with no luck. I can't do something that I don't know how to.

Comment: This can be marked as a dublicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357805/send-larger-messages-than-126-bytes-websockets-in-c-sharp